# Can react native be installed in AMD processor?

Tags: react-native, installation, amd-processor

I use a laptop with AMD processor. I've tried install react, but problematic on its haxm. Is there any other way for me to install react-native on AMD?

Answer (score 0):

You can install all the dependencies needed to use React-Native on a computer with AMD processors. The problem is that, at the moment, Android Studio has no emulators running the requiered version of Android that are also compatible with AMD architecture; so you won't be able to test your application on the Virtual Device provided by Android Studio.

You may either:
A) Use a physical device (mobile phone) to run your application
B) Download a different emulator and use it as if it was connected through USB

As you won't be using Android Studio emulator, you don´t need to install HAXM